# What is the difference between the demand schedule and the demand curve?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, supply-and-demand, monopoly

What is the difference between the demand schedule and the demand curve that a monopolist or monopsonist has? Could someone provide details for both cases or even some paradigm or a graph. I can not clarify this concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demand schedule** is a table that gives you the quantity demanded at different prices.

An example of demand schedule that I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Market_Demand_Schedule_copy.png) is shown below:

[image]

**Demand curve** is a curve that plots the demand at different prices in the 2D space defined by $Q$ and $P$ (see example picture I took from investopedia below).

Demand curve is essentially a plot of demand schedule.

[image]

Comment: Why is it necessarily continuous?

Comment: @Giskard you are right I corrected it - I just wanted to highlight that demand schedule is usually discrete and demand would be a continuous plot of the discrete demand schedule but you are right it’s not correct to just say demand curve is continuous I dropped that

Comment: After all, is it continuous or not?

Comment: @HungerLearn the one example depicted is continuous and in entry level classes you would most likely always encounter continuous demand functions but in principle there could be discontinuities due to kinks, or because the function is piece-wise and so on.

Comment: I am not familiar with the word ''kinks''. Do you mean something like ''jumps''?

Comment: @HungerLearn actually I made a mistake kink does not necessarily mean function is discontinuous at a point (only that it fails to have a derivative at that point) a kink would be a place on a function where it suddenly changes direction for example for a function that looks like a letter V kink would be the bottom of V but does not necessarily imply that the function is discontinuous at that point - I wanted to correct it but you can edit comments only up to 5 min

Comment: Ok! Let me put the discussion in this way. So, the demand schdule is like you are saying ''give me the prices to tell you my demand of the good/asset at any quoted price" right? But, the demand curve it the demand of an individual in the defined by prices and quantities. Again, I can not understand what the difference is between them...I think it is the same...

Comment: @HungerLearn no demand curve can be aggregated as well. The difference is that schedule is a table - if you look up schedule in dictionary table is one of the definitions while demand curve is a plot of all demanded Q and P. In fact a simple way of estimating demand curve you might learn in first economics course might be just first plot the points from demand schedule in Q P space and then connect the dots